# Infragistics XamDatagrid column resizing left to right

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I use XamDataGrid to show table with really long header names. Most important part of the header name is it's suffix.

Is there any way that I can configure column headers the way that when the column width is shorter than text size i will see the suffix as header?

Example:

Required outcome:

```
[...SUFFIX1][...SUFFIX2]
```

Instead of default behaviour I have:

```
[Prefix....][Prefix....]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way is to create ContentTemplate for LabelPresenter :

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"
TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">

                            </TextBlock>

                        </DataTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
```

the result looks like :

[image]

**for showing the suffix part you can use textwrapping and increasing the height of the LabelPresenters to wrap text. It's a better way to show whole column name and it looks good also.(obviously if this servers your purpose)**

```
<Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
```

set labelPresenter height in style & result looks like  :

[image]

But if you want strictly as you mentioned then use a control as in below link and then use that control in content template of label presenter.

[Textbox with ellipsis](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/309927/WPF-TextBox-With-Ellipsis)